# App intro images - Android-

Tags: android, image, resolution

i'm creating some app intros for my Android app with photoshop and illustrator. The images that i'm creating are very very large in terms of resolution. How to make them fit in all android devices without distorting their propotions? 
Ps: I didn't try yet to load these images into a device, is it a good idea to resize them according to the android default Dpi resolutions (ldpi,hdpi,xhdpi etc...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). It can handle resizing and image loading for you.